# Extension-B characters and iOS

Tags: ios, unicode, fonts

Does iOS support viewing of extension-B Unicode characters ? My UILabel shows garbage characters. Even the mail client and browser on iOS shows garbage characters. For eg:- try to open this page in the safari browser on iOs
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_Unified_Ideographs,_Extension_B_(Part_1_of_7)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_Unified_Ideographs,_Extension_B_%28Part_1_of_7%29)

thanks

Comment: You probably need to use a font that has proper glyphs for those characters.

Comment: CJK Unified Ideograms Extension B characters have very limited support in fonts (cf. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20000/fontsupport.htm), but in lack of a suitable font, they should normally be indicated by symbols for unrepresentable characters, not “garbage”. It is not obvious from the description what actually gets displayed.